# How to get the name of a dictionary from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries, how do I access the name of the dictionaries (not the key names)?

```
`list_of_dicts = [
sen_score_1, 
sen_score_2, 
sen_score_3, 
sen_score_4,
sen_score_5, 
sen_score_6, 
sen_score_7, 
sen_score_8, 
sen_score_9, 
sen_score_10, 
sen_score_11, 
sen_score_12, 
sen_score_13, 
sen_score_14,
sen_score_15
]
for i in list_of_dicts:
    #get the dicts name`
```

Comment: 1. Those are not the correct brackets to create a list. Did you mean `[]`? 2. During the creation, python already substitutes the variable names with the references. You cannot get the "name" of the dict because it was only a variable name all along, not connected to the object itself

Comment: yes, i did mean square brackets. ok is there a way to get the variable name or set one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it. However, you can use a tuple `(string, dict)`.
For example, you can have:

```
list_of_dicts = [
  ('sen_score_1', sen_score_1),
  ('sen_score_2', sen_score_2),
  ...
]
```

And then you can access name by `e[0]` and dict by `e[1]`, like follows:

```
for e in list_of_dicts:
    print("Name: {}, Dict: {}".format(e[0], e[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed! but how do I now access the keys in the dictionary

Comment: Ah i see but what do you mean by arr_index?

Comment: @LewisRevel The index inside list_of_dicts list. 0 is for ('sen_score_1', sen_score_1), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

by dictionary name you simply mean variable name , variable names are for addressing to the variable and they're names aren't stored , so you have to store variable names too , in your case dictionary names
use a dictionary to store your dictionaries instead of list and then get all the keys :

```
dic_of_dics = {
   'sen_score_1':sen_score_1,
   'sen_score_2':sen_score_2,..}
```

and then get

```
dic_of_dics.keys()
```

or maybe try storing them as tuples inside a list

```
list_of_tuple = {
   ('sen_score_1',sen_score_1),
   ('sen_score_2',sen_score_2),..}
```

and then :

```
for i in list_of_tuple :
   print(i[0])
```

Comment: How would i access the keys of every dictionary in this dictionary?

Comment: @LewisRevel dic_of_dics.values() simply creates a list of dictionaries using a for you can access every  one of them lets call it A_DIC then using A_DIC.keys() you'll have keys of every dictionary .